# How do I adjust my window buttons to the left or right?

Tags: 11.10, gconf, window-buttons

I'm trying to use gconf-editor to make an adjustment to my Windows. In the past I had the close,min,max to the "RIGHT". Now I'd like to switch back to the "LEFT". The old way doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried gconf-editor, but I get errors. I did a fresh install of 11.10, but I had my home in another partition. Not sure if my old settings are causing the issue. Can anyone make a suggestion?

> ** (gconf-editor:2397): WARNING **: Index value is too large
>
> (gconf-editor:2397): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_get_valist:
>   property `type' of object class`GConfEditorWindow' is not readable
>
> (gconf-editor:2397): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_get_valist:
>   property `type' of object class`GConfEditorWindow' is not readable
>   GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error:
>   Method "AllDirs" with signature "s" on interface
>   "org.gnome.GConf.Database" doesn't exist
>
> ** (gconf-editor:2397): WARNING **: Index value is too large
>
> GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error:
>   Method "AllDirs" with signature "s" on interface
>   "org.gnome.GConf.Database" doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing gconf-editor and all its configuration files and then reinstalling.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove gconf-editor
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

If that doesn't work, you should look to deleting old setting as these maybe causing many problems, including this one. I also have a separate /home partition but always erase config folders/files when upgrading to a new version.

Comment: Thanks for the added comment about the config folders/files when upgrading.

Comment: --purge remove seemed to help. I then moved the menu: to the end "minimize,maximize,close:menu". It seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What about this command:

```
gconftool -s /apps/metacity/general/button_layout -t string menu:minimize,maximize,close
```